# TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid I got this error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Giving a unique code by seeing the first column string and the second columns string and whenever the first column string change it starts from 1

Example:

[image]

I use this code:

```
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby('colummen1')))
for _, df in dfs.items():

 df['id'] = df.groupby(['colummen1','colummun2']).ngroup()  

dfs = [df[1] for df in dfs]
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

but I get this error:

[image]

Comment: `df[1]` is the first element of the `df`. What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be updated in the following way:

```
import pandas as pd

# set data
data = {"colummen1": ["Kenbele1", "Kenbele1", "Kenbele1", "Kenbele1", "Kenbele2", "Kenbele2", "Kenbele2", "Kenbele2"], 
        "colummun2": ["Commutity1", "Commutity2", "Commutity3", "Commutity4", "Commutity1", "Commutity2", "Commutity3", "Commutity4"]}

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

dfs = df.groupby('colummen1')

dfs_updated = []

for _, df in dfs:
    df['id'] = df.groupby(['colummen1','colummun2']).ngroup()+1
    dfs_updated.append(df)
    
df_new = pd.concat(dfs_updated)

df_new
```

Returns

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear what you expect, but when you write `df[1] for df in dfs`, then your `df` is a key (for example *Kebele 1*) and `df[1]` is a character (for example *e* - second character of the string).

That is why you get this error, because your array `dfs` is constructed out of 2 characters `["e", "e"]`. Therefore you can not concatenate it.

I think with `df[1]` you meant the data frame, that is associated with the key, if so, then the code should look like this:

```
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby('colummen1')))

for _, df in dfs.items():
    df['id'] = df.groupby(['colummen1','colummun2']).ngroup()  

dfs = [df for _, df in dfs.items()]
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```